# How to define and use a struct with an optional property in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to have a model "places" that has a optional.

```
struct PlaceObj: Identifiable {
let id = UUID()
let name: String
let image: UIImage
}
```

Not every PlaceItem may have an image, so I wanted to keep it optional. I would like to use it like:

```
PlaceObj(
name: "Place1"
)
```

But that gives me an error that image is not defined, this means I have to do:

```
PlaceObj(
name: "Place1",
image: nil
)
```

But I can't do nil unless I put a questionmark after UIImage.
Is there a best practice/preferred way to handle this? Is there no way to just omit "image:nil" from every instantiation when trying to use it?

Comment: `Looks like there is no such thing as an optional` huh?

Comment: @Alexander updated my question to make more sense of what I am after.

Comment: I get what your after overall, but I don't understand what you mean by that sentence

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give it a default value of `nil`, and that compiler-generated default memberwise initializer will have defaulted parameters to match, thanks to [SE-0242 – Synthesize default values for the memberwise initializer](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0242-default-values-memberwise.md):

```
struct PlaceObj: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    var image: UIImage? = nil
}
```

The compiler-provided initializer will behave as if you wrote:

```
init(name: String, image: UIImage? = nil) {
    self.name = name
    self.image = image
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your own initializer:

```
struct PlaceObj: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let image: UIImage?
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.image = nil
    }
}
```

Then:
`let b = PlaceObj(name: "Bob")`

or (thanks to @Alexander's comment):

```
struct PlaceObj: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    var image: UIImage? = nil
}
```

which avoids having to make an initializer, but keep in mind it is only available in Swift 5.1+

Comment: To confirm my understanding, is it normal to support multiple init statements for a struct? so one could be init(image: UIImage) { self.name = "Unknown", self.image = image}, and the other would be what you have there?

Comment: If you make the `image` into `var image: UIImate? = nil`, then you wouldn't need to hand-roll this initializer, thanks to [SE-0242 – Synthesize default values for the memberwise initializer](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0242-default-values-memberwise.md)

Comment: @Rolando It's not uncommon, although it's usually best to have initializers forward to other initializes, forming a tree of calls that's rooted with one master init, similar to `convenience`/`required` initializers. It's not enforced for structs as it is for classes, but it's still useful to have a "all roads lead to Rome" initializer (for example, it's one place where you can put a breakpoint and *know* it'll get hit if *any* `PlaceObj` is ever made, regardless of which initializer was called first in the chain)

Comment: Thanks, I noticed "let image: UIImage?" triggers an error without having the image field, but using var works fine. Is it better practice to use the init or stick with the var? (or does it not matter and both are equally fine)

Comment: Out of laziness, I would opt for `var image: UIImage? = nil`, and have the compiler generate the init. If I had a different reason that forces me to write out my own init, then I would prefer `let image: UIImage?`, and handle the default value myself. I really with `SE-0242` didn't require the property to be mutable.